# ArgumentException: Scene to unload is invalid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why is the scene invalid

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("blue");
            SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync("red");
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("red");
            SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync("blue");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you load a scene in single mode, as you are doing, the current scene is removed so there is not need to try and unload it. It's already gone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `Why is the scene invalid` -> because it isn't loaded

Answer (score 0):

`Why is the scene invalid`

⇒ because it **isn't loaded**!

After the synchronous call

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("red");
```

which [by default is in **Single** mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html), any other scene is already unloaded so there is no need/use of calling

```
SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync("blue");
```